# How to write a html file using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I used below HTML code and php code to Write new files.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="write.php" method="get">
ID : <input type="text" name="ID"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
  $myfile = fopen($_GET["ID"] , "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt = "Your user ID =";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
  $txt = $_GET["ID"];
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

If I submit TEST to html form , php code writes a file named "test". it hasn't a file extension.
How to write "TEST.html" with above code.?

Comment: `$_GET["ID"]."html"`. but here i think `.html` is worthless. you need to add `.txt`extension.

Comment: Why would you be trying to create an html page for each user ID? This seems like a monumentally bad idea.

Comment: I am creating a simple affiliate system for few publishers.I create separate html files for each users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `.html` with a `!empty()` check there, like below:-

```
<?php
 if(!empty($_GET['ID'])){ // check first that ID is coming or not
   $myfile = fopen($_GET["ID"]."html" , "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $txt = "Your user ID =";
   fwrite($myfile, $txt); 
   $txt = $_GET["ID"];
   fwrite($myfile, $txt);
   fclose($myfile);
 }
?>
```

***To open and read this file:-***

```
 <?php
   if(!empty($_GET['ID'])){ // check first that ID is coming or not
     $myfile = fopen($_GET["ID"]."html", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
     echo fread($myfile,filesize($_GET["ID"])); 
     fclose($myfile);
   }
?>
```

***OR:-***

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['ID'])){ // check first that ID is coming or not
  $file = fopen($_GET["ID"]."html","r") or die("Unable to open file!"); ;

  while(! feof($file)){
    echo fgets($file). "<br />";
  }

  fclose($file);
}
?>
```

***Note:-***

In my opinion you need `.txt` rather than `.html`.An HTML file with text like `test` really have no mean, or server any useful purpose. BTW it's up-to-you what extension you want. I just gave my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Add the extension to the filename before opening the file:-

```
$filename = $_GET["ID"] . '.html';

$myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

**Note** You are opening up yourself to all kinds of security issues here.

Comment: how to open above html file using this code  <?php
$myfile = fopen($_GET["ID"], "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize($_GET["ID"]));
fclose($myfile);
?>

Comment: Just pass in `$filename` as created above to the functions instead of `$_GET["ID"]`.

Answer (score 1):

just use this code:-

```
fopen($_GET["ID"].'.html' , "w")
```